# Excel VB script to print all workbooks' sheets

Tags: excel, vba

is there using excel's vb script (or macros) to print all its sheets to a given printer ? The number of sheets is variable.

Excel's version is 2007.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if something [like this](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/05/print-multiple-sheets-using-vba.html) is what you are looking for.  You'd just need to set up a loop to select all of the sheets, and use that `select false` method on all but the first.

Here's what I cobbled together (I did not test it extensively, and my VBA is a little rusty)

```
Sub loopandprint()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 0
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (i = 0) Then
        ws.Select
    Else
        ws.Select False

    End If

  i = i + 1
  Next ws
  ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually I need to iterate over the sheets because its number may vary.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by set up a loop.  I didn't say it would be a perfect fit :)  See [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=390) for how to iterate over all the sheets.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Finally could you tell me how to print one sheet at a time ?

Comment: The first link covered that too, you just put the sheet number in the `()`, like `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select` where I have `ws.select` in the sample.  Or do you mean selecting them another way?